# How to sort a file in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, pdf

I want to know how to sort a file in an unix shell? Is there any tools outta there?

Comment: Lack of research, a quick google search would have pointed you in the right direction immediately.

Comment: @Shads0 Outright guessing would have put him in the right direction!

Answer (score 13):

The sort command is named [sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort).